# Android, Java - How to use one DTO in two classes

Tags: java, android, gps, dto

I'm trying to make a map application.

There are two Activities that need to get current location.
The first activity is MainActivity, and all of the codes to get current location are in it.
And the second one is an activity that user can set a departure place.
When an user click a button to set a point of departure as current location, I need to get the values from the MainActivity.

I made CurrentLocationDTO to solve this. But somehow when I call currentDTO.getLatitude() in the second activity, it just returns 0.0. 
I have no idea why it returns initialized value even if it's called after `currentDTO.setLatitude(value);` is all done in MainActivity.

I made the DTO object by writing `CurrentLocationDTO currentDTO = new CurrentLocationDTO();` in each classes. Is it wrong to make it like this? Or is there any other ideas to solve this problem, please share with me.

here's MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

private final String TMAP_API_KEY = "10062d5b-d3d3-4b7d-8977-acd3ac2dc390";
LocationManager lm;
TMapView tMapView;
EditText Departure, Arrival;
Button Search;
LinearLayout Layout;
FloatingActionButton Current, Navigate;
String D_lon;
String D_lat;
String A_lon;
String A_lat;


//floatingActionButton 활성화/비활성화
Boolean FabActive = false; //navigate 버튼용
private ArrayList<TMapPoint> arPoint;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout linearLayoutTmap = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutTmap);
    tMapView = new TMapView(this);
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); //위치 관리자 객체 참조


    Departure = findViewById(R.id.departure);
    Arrival = findViewById(R.id.arrival);
    Search = findViewById(R.id.search);
    Layout = findViewById(R.id.search_layout);
    Current = findViewById(R.id.current_location);
    Navigate = findViewById(R.id.navigate);

    tMapView.setSKTMapApiKey(TMAP_API_KEY);
    linearLayoutTmap.addView(tMapView);
    tMapView.setIconVisibility(true);

    setGps();



    Departure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapListActivity.class), 200);
        }
    });

    Arrival.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapListActivity.class), 300);
        }
    });
}




public void setGps() {
    //final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, // 등록할 위치제공자(실내에선 NETWORK_PROVIDER 권장)
            1000, // 통지사이의 최소 시간간격 (miliSecond)
            1, // 통지사이의 최소 변경거리 (m)
            mLocationListener);

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, // 등록할 위치제공자(실내에선 NETWORK_PROVIDER 권장)
            1000, // 통지사이의 최소 시간간격 (miliSecond)
            1, // 통지사이의 최소 변경거리 (m)
            mLocationListener);

}

private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        double latitude;
        double longitude;

        if (location != null) {
            CurrentLocationDTO currentLocationDTO = new CurrentLocationDTO();
            //I get values from location object here, and use setter to store it
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            currentLocationDTO.setLatitude(latitude);
            currentLocationDTO.setLongitude(longitude);
            Log.e("Test", currentLocationDTO.getLatitude() + ", " + currentLocationDTO.getLongitude()); //I can get proper values here
            Log.e(TAG, latitude + " , " + longitude);
            tMapView.setLocationPoint(longitude, latitude);
            tMapView.setCenterPoint(longitude, latitude);

        }

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 200) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String D_str = data.getStringExtra("selected");
            D_lat = data.getStringExtra("lat");
            D_lon = data.getStringExtra("lon");
            Departure.setText(D_str);
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "requestCode= " + requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Toast.makeText(this, D_str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "lat : " + D_lat + " lon : " + D_lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == 300) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String A_str = data.getStringExtra("selected");
            A_lat = data.getStringExtra("lat");
            A_lon = data.getStringExtra("lon");
            Arrival.setText(A_str);
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "requestCode= " + requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, A_str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And This one is CurrentLocationDTO.java

```
package com.example.gpgpt.myapplication;

public class CurrentLocationDTO {

private double latitude;
private double longitude;
public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

}

MapListActivity.java - I tried to use `getter` but it returns initial values of DTO

```
      Current.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CurrentLocationDTO currentLocationDTO = new CurrentLocationDTO();
            double lon = currentLocationDTO.getLongitude();
            double lat = currentLocationDTO.getLatitude();
            currentLocationDTO.setLongitude(13.8);
            Text.setText(lon+", "+lat);
        }
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: can we see your `MainActivity`

Comment: @user3170251 sorry for the late reply. I edited my post.

Comment: In your `onclick(View v)` listener, you're creating a new object, hence the reason why you're getting initial values.  Instead, you would need to transfer the `currentLocationDTO` from your `MainActivity` to your `MapListActivity`. [Here's a good guide on how to pass data between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: @user3170251 Hello! I solved this problem using `SharedPreferences` at the end. but I also referred the link you gave me too. Thank you for your help! :)